# Shifted two-sided Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $(B_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ be a two-sided Brownian motion, defined as
$B(t) = \begin{cases} B_1(t),\quad t >0 \\
0, \quad t = 0 \\
B_2(-t), \quad t < 0 \end{cases}$. For some $a>0$ let $T:=\inf\{t\geq 0: B_t=a\}$ be the hitting time of $a$. By the strong Markov property, the process $(B_{T+t}-B_T)_{t\geq0}$ is a standard Brownian Motion.

I know that $(B_{T+t}-B_T)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ is not a two-sided Brownian motion, but I cannot find a rigorous argument to prove it. I get the idea that if one goes backwards in time (from $T$ to $0$), one gets something negative, which cannot be normally distributed, but I don't manage to write it down appropriately. I am grateful for any help you might give me.

Comment: It looks like you made a copy/paste error and your question became rather garbled.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Someone indicated to me a reference to the answer, so I will also post it here.

It has to do with a theorem in this paper: Path Decomposition and
Continuity of Local Time for One-Dimensional Difussions, I - by David Williams, which says that on the interval $[0,T_c]$, the process $(c-X_{T_c -t})$ is equal in distribution to  a Bessel Process. The argument seems quite complicated to me and I haven't studied it in great detail yet, but I thought that for completion an answer is due.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a detailed enough usage of your argument.

Define $\tilde B$ by $\tilde B_t = B_{T+t} - B_t$. 
As you said, if this were a two-sided Brownian motion (say its left side was $\tilde B_2$), we have a positive probability that it is a positive number:
$$ P\big(\tilde B_{-T/2} \in [0,\infty)\big) = P\big( \tilde B_2(T/2) \in [0,\infty)\big) = 1/2. $$

On the other hand, because $B_1$ is almost-surely continuous, we have that $B_1|_{[0,T/2]} < a$ almost-surely, by the intermediate value theorem and definition of our stopping time $T$.
Consequently, $B_{T/2}-B_T < 0$ almost-surely.
This means that
$$ P\big(\tilde B_{-T/2} \in [0,\infty)\big) = P\big( B_{T/2} - B_T \in [0,\infty) \big) = 0. $$

Comment: I think you mean $\tilde{B}_t:=B_{T+t}-B_T$, not $\tilde{B}_t:=B_{T+t}-B_t$. And I am not sure what result implies your first claim, namely that $\tilde{B}_{-T/2}$ should be normally distributed. What you say is that if you have a Brownian motion $B$, then $B_T$ should be normally distributed, for a stopping time $T$. I don't think this is true.

Comment: Oh, very good point. I definitely jumped the gun there. I can't simply use the normal increments argument with stopping times.

Comment: How about considering the event $\bigcap_{q\in(0,1)\cap\mathbb Q}\bigg(\tilde B_{-qT}\in(0,\infty)\bigg)$? I think this should have probability zero by definition of the stopping time, so continuity of Brownian motion would tell us that almost every path is negative on $[-T,0]$.